# R: calculate rank sum automatically

Tags: r, math, sum, duplicates, rank

Given `x <- cbind(c(10,15,20,20,25,30,30,30,35,40,40,40,40,45),rep(c('M','F'),7))`, I want to calculate the rank sums of of categories M and F *automatically*, without doing it by hand. The thing I couldn't figure out is how to adjust the rank numbers when there is a tie. In this case, #3 and #4 are both 20 and thus share the rank value of 3.5 (instead of 3 and 4). Likewise #6 ~ #8 have the rank value of 7, and #10 ~ #13 have 11.5. Without this adjustment, the sums would be wrong.

`#Wrong`

`sum(which(x[,2]=='F')) # =56`

`sum(which(x[,2]=='M')) # =49`

`#Right`

`sum(1,3.5,5,7,9,11.5,11.5) # =56.5`

`sum(2,3.5,7,7,11.5,11.5,14) # =48.5`

I've tried `table()` and `duplicated()`, but couldn't figure out how to piece things together. Any ideas?

EDIT: My thanks to konvas for suggesting `rank()`, which works in addition to bgoldst's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`sum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) the [`rank()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rank.html) with [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html):

```
x <- data.frame(age=c(10,15,20,20,25,30,30,30,35,40,40,40,40,45),sex=rep(c('M','F'),7));
aggregate(rank(age)~sex, x, sum );
##   sex rank(age)
## 1   F      56.5
## 2   M      48.5
```

Comment: No need for `;`, it is not Matlab.

Comment: @Pascal, I always terminate statements with semicolons in virtually all languages I work in (C/C++/Java/R/bash/SQL/Perl). I prefer the consistency and explicitness of it.

Comment: Maybe, but not needed in R.

Comment: Not needed in bash either, and I take flak for it there too.

Comment: A tiny bit useless, R tend to be functional: exporting other langage feature and habit like C is a bad habit. You should rather adapt to the langage.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, you are correct, they are functionally useless in the context in which I've used them, and it is certainly not advisable to import features from other languages into one's current language. But this is not what I have done. Semicolons are a feature of the R language. They are necessary to separate statements when coding multiple statements onto a single line. Thus, I prefer consistency not just between languages, but between statement termination for both single-statement and multi-statement lines within R. It is therefore more for human readability than anything else.

Comment: Wow, this is super neat. Thanks bgoldst!

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x <- cbind(c(10,15,20,20,25,30,30,30,35,40,40,40,40,45),rep(c('M','F'),7))
data.frame(x) %>% mutate(rank=rank(X1)) %>% group_by(X2) %>% summarise(sum(rank))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base `R`, you can use `ave`:

```
setNames(unique(ave(rank(x[,1]), x[,2], FUN=sum)), unique(x[,2]))
#    M    F 
# 48.5 56.5
```

Comment: Using `tapply` would be more direct i.e. `tapply(rank(x[,1]), x[,2], FUN=sum)` instead of the `unique`